# React-native: save data in device memory

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I know about `asyncStorage`. That's not what i need. I want to save some data locally, so if app will be completely deleted and installed again, it should gain access to the stored data. AsyncStorage data being removed along with app itself.

Answer (score 2):

I think you must use a `FileSystem` to save files in phone storage. Take a look at this library to handle files: https://github.com/johanneslumpe/react-native-fs. Hope it helps.

Comment: @stkvtflw please consider to mark this answer as the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think anything an app creates can exist after app deletion. If you think about it, why would you want disk space being used up by an app you deleted. Only option I can think of is storing in the cloud: Google Drive, DropBox, etc. or a server you run and user data connected to an account system. 
My experience is with iOS, maybe Android has some option for what you want.